# How can i prevent dereferencing using cpp

Tags: c++, pointers

I am having following code in my cpp file,too many dereferencing are getting here, can anybody suggest me what can i do to prevent this .

```
        aObj* bObj = NULL;
        bObj = getG()->getO(bObjId);
        AbstractionType eAT= bObj->GetAT();
        long nObjType = bObj->GetOT()
```

Comment: Why do you think it´s too many? If you want to change this, redesign your program. (And depending on what it is, may it won´t get better)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a reference to the object the pointer tracks:

```
aObj* p_bObj = getG()->getO(bObjId);
aObj& bObj = *p_bObj;  // <-- once for convenience
AbstractionType eAT= bObj.GetAT();  // use .-notation however-many times
long nObjType = bObj.GetOT();
```

If you need the pointer (`p_bObj` above) to `delete` the object later, consider storing it in a `std::unique_ptr<>` or `std::shared_ptr<>` instead of an `aObj*` - that way you can be sure of `delete`-ion even if the program "tries to circumvent" the `delete` due to an exception, `return`, `break`, `goto` etc..

If you don't also need a pointer at all then you could create the reference directly:

```
aObj& bObj = *(getG()->getO(bObjId));
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, I will try to make essential changes n code..it might work.